# how to make a constructor object in class object can be applied to given types?

Tags: java

1. Write a class with the name Circle. The class needs one field (instance variable) with name radius of type double.

The class needs to have one constructor with parameter radius of type double and it needs to initialize the fields.

In case the radius parameter is less than 0 it needs to set the radius field value to 0.

Write the following methods (instance methods):

- Method named getRadius without any parameters, it needs to return the value of radius field.
- Method named getArea without any parameters, it needs to return the calculated area (radius * radius * PI). For PI use Math.PI constant.

2. Write a class with the name Cylinder that extends Circle class. The class needs one field (instance variable) with name height of type double.

The class needs to have one constructor with two parameters radius and height both of type double. It needs to call parent constructor and initialize a height field.

In case the height parameter is less than 0 it needs to set the height field value to 0.

Write the following methods (instance methods):

- Method named getHeight without any parameters, it needs to return the value of height field.
- Method named getVolume without any parameters, it needs to return the calculated volume. To calculate volume multiply the area with height.

TEST EXAMPLE

→ TEST CODE:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(3.75);
System.out.println("circle.radius= " + circle.getRadius());
System.out.println("circle.area= " + circle.getArea());
Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(5.55, 7.25);
System.out.println("cylinder.radius= " + cylinder.getRadius());
System.out.println("cylinder.height= " + cylinder.getHeight());
System.out.println("cylinder.area= " + cylinder.getArea());
System.out.println("cylinder.volume= " + cylinder.getVolume());
```

→ OUTPUT

```
circle.radius= 3.75
circle.area= 44.178646691106465
cylinder.radius= 5.55
cylinder.height= 7.25
cylinder.area= 96.76890771219959
cylinder.volume= 701.574580913447
```

NOTE: All methods should be defined as public NOT public static.

NOTE: In total, you have to write 2 classes.

NOTE: Do not add a main method to the solution code.

this is my Circle class

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        if(radius < 0){
            radius = 0;
            return radius;
        }else{
            return radius;
        }
    }

    public double getArea(){
        double area = (radius * radius * Math.PI);
        return area;
    }
}
```

this is my Cylinder Class

```
public class Cylinder extends Circle{
    private double height;

    public Cylinder(double radius, double height) {
        super(radius);
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        if(height > 0){
            return height;
        }else{
            height = 0;
            return height;
        }
    }

    public double getVolume(){
        double area = getArea() * getHeight();
        return area;
    }
}
```

But the question said that constructor object in class object cannot be applied to given types and that super(radius) required no arguments. and I also get an error at the double area = getArea() * getHeight(); that said cannot find symbol. can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: "In case the radius parameter is less than 0 it needs to set the radius field value to 0." The code for this should be in the constructor, not the instance methods.

Comment: The question is flawed in its modelling: if Cylinder extends Circle, then all Cylinders are Circles. But a cylinder isn't a circle, it's a 3d shape, not a 2d shape.

Comment: The problems you describe in your last paragraph make it sound like you are extending a different `Circle` class. Are you sure you are extending the one you have defined?

Comment: Thank you so much ill try to fix by putting the if statement in the constructor

Comment: i did put the if statement inside the constructor but it still gives me the same error

Comment: If you click on the class Circle in the statement class Cylinder extends Circle, do you fall into your Circle class? I think @AndyTurner is right, the code shouldn't raise the error you mention.

Comment: technically the code works fine but the question isn't accepting my code and said there is 2 error

Answer (score 1):

private double radius;

```
public Circle(double radius) {
    if (radius < 0) {
        this.radius = 0;
    } else {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

}

public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public double getArea() {

    return this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI;

}
```

The Cylinder class:
public class Cylinder extends Circle {
private double height;

```
public Cylinder(double radius, double height) {
    super(radius);
    if (height < 0) {
        this.height = 0;
    } else {
        this.height = height;
    }

}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public double getVolume() {
    return getArea() * this.height;
}
```

}

!!!But it's important to put Cylinder  EXTENDS  Circle on Udemy course, for right compile...